# Dealing with DB null using Talend Routine

Tags: java, talend

So I have been working with Talend lately, and every thing is fantastic; however, I have been facing a "NullException" problem. I have a double datatype field in the database which could have a null value. Now I have tried in my routine the usual try catch but still the NullException is still thrown. Now I know that double is not nullable in Java and my question is, how can I check for null for those fields in the table that could be null (Especially, the double data type)

Answer (score 1):

Change your double datatype to Double because double is a primitive datatype which doesn't accept null and Double is class.

After changing it to Double, you can directly check your NULL on it using ==.

Comment: if(X.isNaN()  || Y.isNaN() || X == null || Y == null )
   {
    return false;
   }

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your statement is

```
if(X.isNaN() || Y.isNaN() || X == null || Y == null ) { return false; }
```

The `NullException` would relate to the value being `null`, but not being `NaN`.

To find out the difference, you should check for `null` first and *then* try to access the value inside the variables, meaning a reversed order and slightly different brackets:

```
if((X == null || X.isNaN()) || (Y == null || Y.isNaN())) { return false; }
```